# split apk for densities: Galaxy S8+, Note 8, Galaxy S9+, Note 9 not supported

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm building multiple apks for an app to reduce apk size, using screen densities, like this:

```
splits {


    density {


        enable true
        reset()

        include "mdpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"

        compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'

    }
}
```

Some devices can't receive this version of the app, and looking in the device catalog it says:

> Doesn't support required screen densities & sizes 
>   - 640, SMALL
>   - 640, NORMAL
>   - 640, LARGE
>   - 640, XLARGE

Is there a way to target these devices in the split? I can't use the universal apk because it's too big, and expansion files are not an option for this project.

Comment: These compatible screens is deprecated long time from now. You should use sw<dp> notations for creating your folders

Comment: try to build split apk for ldpi

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this post https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/smallerapk-part-4-multi-apk-through-abi-and-density-splits-477083989006

> Unfortunately, only named densities currently work with the include/exclude statements for now, so you can’t create an APK that targets 280/360/420/480/560 dpi devices.

The solution posted in the article works. Here is the relevant part of the module level build.gradle:

```
ext.densityCodes = ['mdpi': 1, 'hdpi': 2, 'xhdpi': 3, 'xxhdpi': 4, 'xxxhdpi': 5]
ext.additionalDensities = ['xhdpi': ['280'], 'xxhdpi': ['420', '400', '360'], 'xxxhdpi': ['560']]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

variant.outputs.each { output ->
    if (output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY) != null && project.ext.additionalDensities.containsKey(output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY))) {
        output.processManifest.doFirst {
            def manifestFile = new File(project.buildDir, "intermediates" + File.separator + "manifests" + File.separator + "density" + File.separator +  variant.buildType.name  + File.separator + output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY) + File.separator + "AndroidManifest.xml")
            def manifestText = manifestFile.text
            for (String density : project.ext.additionalDensities.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY))) {
                manifestText = manifestText.replaceAll("</compatible-screens>", "<screen android:screenSize=\"small\" android:screenDensity=\"${density}\" />\n" +
                        "<screen android:screenSize=\"large\" android:screenDensity=\"${density}\" />\n" +
                        "<screen android:screenSize=\"xlarge\" android:screenDensity=\"${density}\" />\n" +
                        "<screen android:screenSize=\"normal\" android:screenDensity=\"${density}\" />\n </compatible-screens>")
            }
            manifestFile.text = manifestText
        }
    }

    def baseAbiVersionCode =
            project.ext.densityCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY))

    if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

        output.versionCodeOverride =
                baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
    }
}
```

}

I modified this line

```
def manifestFile = new File(project.buildDir, "intermediates" + File.separator + "manifests" + File.separator + "density" + File.separator +  variant.buildType.name  + File.separator + output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY) + File.separator + "AndroidManifest.xml")
```

because of the different position of variant.buildType.name in the filesystem.